# Equivalent of UNIX statement in Windows Batch

Tags: unix, batch-file, awk

What is the equivalent of this statement in batch?

```
awk '/-imsi/ {print $NF "\r"}' "IMSI$r.txt" | tee -a out > "N$r"
```

This statement is in a loop were the variable r  is incremented.
It will search in the text file for -imsi and take the last <del>record</del>*field* after it, then save the output in 2 files, out and N*r*.txt

I couldn't find any batch command that replaces the awk command.

Comment: Since tagged with Unix, I suggest scp that file to Unix machine, the you have (n)awk, tee. ^_*

Comment: My understanding is that CygWin will get you a (slightly crippled, but still) Unix-like environment on Windows.  Clunky as it may seem, it may be the least cumbersome solution.

Comment: Or [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) provides [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) and [tee](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

Comment: `cygwin` is excellent, been using it for years and couldn't function without it. It has the ability to launch Windows batch scripts so you can, for example, create an icon on your desktop which when double-clicked on will invoke cygwin/bash to run a bash script which will execute a Windows/batch script to, say, extract sheets from an Excel file and convert to CSV and then run an awk script under bash on the result. So you can use Excel to store all your data and give graphical displays, etc. but then use awk to produce subsets/transformations of that data. It provides the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excuse me, I don't know UNIX awk feature. However, the Batch commands below search in the IMSIr.txt file for "-imsi" string and take the string immediately after it; then save the output in 2 files, out (with all output lines) and Nr.txt:

```
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:"-imsi" IMSIr.txt') do set line=%%a
for /F %%a in ("%line:*-imsi=%") do echo %%a>> out & echo %%a> Nr.txt
```

For example, with this input file:

```
Previous line
Target line: -imsi 376 another values
Posterior line
```

The output is "376".

The modification below include a loop where the variable %%r is incremented thru a certain range:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set N=3
for /L %%r in (1,1,%N%) do (
   for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /C:"-imsi" IMSI%%r.txt') do set line=%%a
   for /F %%a in ("!line:*-imsi=!") do echo %%a>> out & echo %%a> N%%r.txt
)
```

If this is not what you want, please describe the desired changes.

Comment: This is only taking the last value after -imsi.
So if i have 
-imsi 376
-imsi 226

The output will be only 226 and not 376 and 226

Comment: @Necro1992: Please, be clearer in your request. Want you _all_ -imsi values that appear in the file? May two or more -imsi values appear _in the same line_? Remember that I don't know how `awk` works!